# Staggered Alike Recycler View

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll, android-gridview

I want to implement list of items, something like this as shown below.

1. ***if total number of items = 1 (show full item)***
2. ***if total number of items = 2 (show 2 items in 2 columns)***
3. ***if total number of items = 3 (show 3 items, 2 in column#1 and 1 in column#2)***
4. ***and so on...***

[image: 4 cases]

***In case of 5 and 6 items, the section should scroll as shown below***

[image: 5 case]

[image: 6 case]

[image]

> I want to implement this, as one of my section in my application. What is the correct way of implementing this in Android, I need a starting point. Is this possible with a recycler view? Please share any library or github project if available.

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can use GridLayoutManager for recycler view with two row. https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can achieve this by using StaggeredLayoutManager, in which you need to set your **span count**  & **Orientation** according to your data size like below code:

```
enter code private void setSpanValue() {
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager;
    if (modelArrayList.size() == 1) {
        staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    } else if (modelArrayList.size() == 2) {
        staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    } else if (modelArrayList.size() == 3) {
        staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    } else if (modelArrayList.size() == 4) {
        staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    } else {
        staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    }

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, modelArrayList, checkEvenOrOdd(modelArrayList.size()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

For more than 4 items you need to check whether the data is even or odd like below code:

```
private boolean checkEvenOrOdd(int n) {
    if ((n % 2) == 0) {
        // number is even
        return true;

    } else {
        // number is odd
        return false;
    }
}
```

Check it out my sample project it will solved your problem
https://github.com/DanishAmjad12/HetrogenousLayout

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with using custom layout-manage. we can modify layout-manger as per our needs.

I have used DelegateAdapter from vlayout git lib and it's really work awesome.
Check below link for more details.

https://github.com/alibaba/vlayout